# Cómo ejecutar una macro al cambiar una celda en googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una macro la cual ordena de menor a mayor un listado de 4 datos, este listado se llena de acuerdo a algunos cambios que realizo en otras celdas. Mi macro, como se los mencionaba no tiene complejidad, solo busca que estos nuevos resultados modificados sean reordenados y por ende me gustaría que sea ejecutada cada vez que se modifique un valor de mi tabla a ordenar, aquí radica el problema ya que no logro dar con el reordenamiento automático cada vez que realizo un cambio en alguna de las celdas involucradas, el código es el siguiente:

```
function Combo() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O33:V36').activate()
  .sort({column: 22, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
```

Cómo ven, es muy sencilla y solo necesito que cuando sea modificado un valor de la columma 22 entre las filas 33 y 36, esta macro sea ejecutada.
Les agradezco mucho por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

En las hojas de cálculo de Google las macros son un tipo especial de código. Cuando se trata de ejecutar algo de forma automática ya no sería una macro, sino una función.

Hay activadores simples e instalables. Los activadores simples usan palabras reservas que en el caso de lo que estás buscando sería `onEdit`. Se usa de la siguiente forma

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Aquí incluye el código
}
```

Los activadores pasan a la función que llaman un objeto evento, en este caso es recibido por el parámetro `e`. Este objeto evento tiene varias propiedades, como `source`, `range`, `value` entre otras. Ver los detalles en las referencias.

Cabe destacar que los activadores simples tiene varias limitaciones, por ejemplo, el tiempo máximo de ejecución es de 30 segundos. En tu caso esto no debe ser problema.

La función quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.rowStart >= 33 && 
     e.range.rowEnd <=36 && 
     e.range.columnStart === 22 && 
     e.range.columnEnd == 22
    ){
    e.source.getRange('O33:V36').sort({column: 22, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events