# Sobre aplicación de macro y ubicación de botón

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando en Google Sheets con la siguiente hoja:

[image: Hoja]

La macro se ejecuta según el **N° de evaluaciones**.

La macro la tengo aplicada al botón "Aplicar", y allí está mi pregunta: en Excel se pueden aplicar las macros haciendo que se ejecuten según el número de la celda, automáticamente. En Google no encontré la forma de hacerlo y tuve que agregar el botón. ¿Alguno sabe cómo lograr que la macro corra al cambiar el valor de la celda?

Con respecto a la macro el código que estoy usando es este:

```
function Neval() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ingreso = libro.getSheetByName("IngresoInformacion");
  var ne = ingreso.getRange(7,3).getValue();

  if(ne == 1){
    ingreso.getRange(8,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 1")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,2).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,2).setValue("")

    & ingreso.getRange(8,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,3).setValue("")
  } else if (ne == 2){
    ingreso.getRange(8,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 1")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 2")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,2).setValue("")

    & ingreso.getRange(8,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,3).setValue("")
  } else {
    ingreso.getRange(8,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 1")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 2")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,2).setValue("Nombre evaluación 3")

    & ingreso.getRange(8,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(9,3).setValue("")
    & ingreso.getRange(10,3).setValue("")
  }

}
```

Comment: Las preguntas en este sitio deben ser específicas, en otras palabras, sólo una pregunta por publicción.

Comment: Perfecto Rubén. Editada la pregunta. Cuando se responda seguiré con la otra.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo ejecutar una macro al cambiar una celda en googlesheet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/348476/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-una-macro-al-cambiar-una-celda-en-googlesheet)

Comment: Hola Esei. Revisé ese link, que también me lo recomendó @Rubén, pero la verdad no he podido relacionarlo con lo que necesito.
En particular no entiendo la línea e.source.getRange("O33:V36"). No entiendo la referencia si los datos se insertan en la columna 22.

Comment: @Andres Google Apps Script usa JavaScript como lenguaje de programación. Te sugiero estudiar lo básico de este lenguaje (objetos, propiedades, ...) para que puedas ser más específico acerca de la ayuda que necesitas.

Comment: @Ruben, gracias por tus respuestas. De hecho acabo de inscribirme en un curso de Java en Coursera para empezar a estudiar programación en ese lenguaje desde cero.
De todas maneras, con respecto a la pregunta original, lo que necesito es que la macro se ejecute cuando cambié el valor de C7. Si es 1, en B8 debe aparecer "Nota 1". Si es 2, en B8 debe aparecer "Nota 1" y en B9 debe aparecer "Nota 2". Si es 3, en B8 debe aparecer "Nota 1", en B9 "Nota 2" y en B10 "Nota 3". Con el código que publiqué lo logro, pero asignando la función al botón "Aplicar".

Comment: @Andres No confundas Java con JavaScript, son dos lenguajes diferentes y cada uno require the ambientes de desarrollo diferente.

Comment: Perfecto @Ruben. Revisaré eso y gracias por la aclaración!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el activador (trigger) simple usando el nombre de función `onEdit` o un activador instalable "edit".

Ejemplo simple:

```javascript
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 1 && e.range.rowStart === 1){
     // poner aquí lo que se debe hacer cuando se edite A1
  }
}
```

Preguntas Relacionadas

- [Cómo ejecutar una macro al cambiar una celda en googlesheet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/348476/65)

Referencias

- https://developer.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developer.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Rubén, hola. Agradezco tu respuesta. Lamentablemente no la entiendo. No me queda claro el papel de e en el ejemplo que incluyes. Si pudieses explicarlo un poco más, por favor. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Andres Por favor lee mi respuesta a la pregunta relacionada.