# traer información de una hoja a otra con app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un código que me trae información de una hoja a otra. Mi problema es que yo quiero crear un activador que cuando se llene la fila de la hoja de origen se envíe esa fila que acaba de ser ingresada y no que me envie toda la data de nuevo.

```js
function consolidar2() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("161Uyxrqp0_PnwznttknqGXMXQfG-_mbWi5LosCNGtgg"); // id de hoja de origen
  var hojaorigen = ss.getSheetByName("DTP"); // nombre  de hoja de origen
  var rangorigen = hojaorigen.getRange(2,1,1000,8).getValues(); // rango a copiar
  var destino = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1VVb53VCWFZKMlZ4BMLrnVL7LV3aWwuWZtb55LwhDrqg"); // hoja de destino
  var ultimafila = destino.getLastRow()+1
  destino.getActiveSheet().getRange(ultimafila,1,1000,8).setValues(rangorigen); // rango donde se copia de la hoja de destino
}
```

Ahora si existe una manera mejor de ejecutar esta tarea que quiero realizar también es bienvenida la sugerencia.

Comment: Ya tenemos varias preguntas sobre activadores de Google Apps Script / Hojas de Cálculo de Google, por ejemplo esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/348476/65. Primero debes decidir si usarás una activador simple o uno instalable, ya que lo hayas decidido, muestras lo que has hecho para crear el activador y adaptar tu código para ser usado con el activador. Si no tienes claro alguna parte del proceso, has tu pregunta más específica.

Comment: ya el link que pasas dice algo sobre ordenar numero y nose que mas, nose como se relaciona con lo que yo deseo. ademas no es un tema de activador yo se realizar un activador como dice la pregunta lo que no quiero es que se envie toda la informacion cuando yo ejecute el scripts. ya que la mayoria de los scripts que eh visto en internet y videos. hacen lo mismo que yo envian toda la informacion de una hoja a otra. yo quiero es que cuando yo ejecute mi codigo solo me envie la ultima fila de la hoja de origen y asi a medida que vayan agregando datos yo pueda tomar la ultima fila.

Comment: No te "cierres" a lo que dice la pregunta, lee la respuesta... en esta expliqué los básico de los activadores. En esta pregunta no se indica que ya sepas como crear un activador.

Comment: ya ruben lo eh leido si  y no. osea como yo tranformaria mi codigo para que mediante un activador solo tome la ultima fila de la hoja de origen alli si me explotas la cabeza.

Comment: Te sugiero usar un activador editar, ya sea simple o instalable así como el objeto evento. Edita la pregunta para mostrar el activador que vas usar y lo que has intentado para identificar la fila que ha sido editada.

Comment: queria activarlo mediante edición  que cada vez que me llegue la informacion a la hoja de origen se active y ejecute el codigo y mande la informacion a la otra hoja. porque de este modo porque tengo una aplicacion conectada a la hoja de calculo y cuando la persona envia los datos de la aplicacion todo la informacion me llega con una fila entera. y con ese codigo si me manda todo la informacion apenas llega a mi hoja hacia la de destino pero cual es mi problema que me manda toda la informacion de la hoja y eso saturaria mi otra hoja :-s nose si me explico bien ruben

Comment: Si los datos son agregados por una aplicación y no por un usuario el activador editar no te va a servir. Deberías editar la pregunta para agregar todos los detalles relevantes a la misma o bien enfocar to pregunta en entender como funciona tu código que actualmente tienes.

Comment: a ver la aplicacion no es relevante lo digo para que tengas una idea de donde viene la data ya que eso lo tengo programado de otro modo. que pasa ahorita cuando yo uso la aplicacion y manda los datos a la hoja yo uso un activador junto cn este codigo y apenas llega la informacion se activa y me envia toda la informacion a otra hoja. eso esta bien. que pasa que cuando la persona vuelve a usar el aplicativo el activador se activa y vuelve a mandar la informacion completa de la hoja y aqui suerge mi problema. porque yo quiero es enviar la ultima fila agregada en la hoja de origen.

Comment: ahora nose como capturar la ultima fila agregada ya que en el codigo yo agarro todo el rango de la hoja var rangorigen = hojaorigen.getRange(2,1,1000,8).getValues() y se que mi problema esta es en esta linea en como capturo la informacion a ser copiada

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta para agregar detalles suficientes para que otros puedan reproducir ese activador.